# Is there web debug toolbar for Spring, like in symfony and django?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

I'm confused, since Spring has huge ecosystem and not web debug toolbar to show requests, internals info, memory etc.

Or am I missing something? I can say that many things work in Java world different then in nodejs/php/django where it is common task to get development web toolbar functionality for rapid development and checks.
Maybe Spring has one but it has totally different name. Anything possible.

Comment: In java we mostly don't need this. If we do we use JMX or some enterprise monitoring tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Spring Actualator Lib.

https://dzone.com/articles/a-look-at-spring-boot-admin
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

Actuators enable production-ready features to a Spring Boot application – without having to actually implement these things yourself.